# How to implement sql Query to do Outer Joins based on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have Table x containing Courses done by Users but another Table y containing courses assigned to users. I need to retrieve all courses with null row if user doesn't complete the Course

[Table M]    [Table X]      [Table Y]
UserId      UserId  Cid      CourseId 
  1                    1                1             1      
  2                       
   2

I need

```
[Table Z]
```

[UserId]     [CourseId]    [F] 
     1                             1                   done 
     1                            2                   not done 
     2                           2                   not done 
     2                            1                     not done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9c06/4)**

```
SELECT tm.userid,
  ty.courseid,
  CASE WHEN tx.cid IS NULL THEN 'not done' ELSE 'done' END AS 'F'
FROM tablem tm
JOIN tabley ty ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN tablex tx ON tm.userid = tx.userid AND ty.courseid = tx.cid
ORDER BY tm.USERID
```